# Barplot with deviations from a non zero number

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have measurements of some variable. All values are positive. In a barchart I want to show all measurements and the deviation of all measurements from the overall mean. Some bars thus go up from the mean and some go down. In order to get such a graph i tried using `offset` from the `barplot` function but that does not work. I found a solution but it is not ideal and prone to mistakes. Applying axes requires some tweaking of the numbers. Is there someone with a more elegant solution to this? Thanks!

```
(aaa    <-  c(1: 10))
(meanz  <-  mean(aaa))

(ccc    <-  aaa-meanz[1])

barplot(ccc, axes=FALSE, ylim=c(-5, 5))
(yvals      <-  c(-5, 0, 5))
(yvalscorr  <-  yvals+meanz)
axis(side=2, at=yvals, labels=yvalscorr,    mgp=c(1,1,1),   outer=TRUE, lwd=2, las=1, cex.axis=1.0,   tck=0.02, hadj=0.5,  padj=0.5, pos=-0.2)
```

This is more or less what i intend to get (though more flexibility with setting axes values at 0 is needed)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about defining a function like this

```
x <- cumsum(runif(10))
zero <- mean(x)

offsetbarplot <- function(x, zero=0, ..., yaxt="c", ylim) {
    xo <- x-zero
    yax <- pretty(x)
    if (missing(ylim)) 
        ylim<-range(yax-zero)
    else
        ylim<-ylim-zero
    barplot(xo, ..., yaxt=ifelse(yaxt=="c","n",yaxt), ylim=ylim)
    if(yaxt=="c") {
        axis(side=2, at=yax-zero, labels=yax)
    }
}

offsetbarplot(x, zero)
```

This way we can use as much of the `barplot` code as possible. You can still pass many of the same options. We just draw a custom axis on the side.

Answer (score 2):

A documented but subtle property of the barplot function is that you can give it a matrix as the data and it will stack the bars, the 2nd row bars starting where the 1st finish at.  You can also specify colors and borders to be `NA` meaning don't plot them.  So this means that if you `rbind` a row of the means to the values that you want to plot (with the mean subtracted), but don't plot the 1st set of bars, you will see what you are asking for.  e.g.:

```
 aaa <- 1:10
 meanz <- mean(aaa)
 ccc <- aaa- meanz
 barplot( rbind( meanz, ccc ), col=c(NA,'grey'), border=c(NA,1)
```

This gives a plot very much like yours, the only visible difference is the y-axis.  An invisible difference is that the coordinate system matches the data of interest which could simplify augmenting the plot.

Comment: This is nice for values near zero. But what about `aaa <- 99:110`. Perhaps you may also wish to set `ylim=range(aaa)`.

Comment: @MrFlick, good point.  I had assumed that the original poster was only going to use this with values close enough that 0 would be included.  Setting `ylim` will work when that is not the case.